# We say "super chill", so is it valid if I say "super mature"?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, superlatives

We say "super chill", so is it valid and if so, why, and can I say "super mature" or "super conscious" or "super popular" ?

Comment: I think the words are enough and adding 'super' would be redundant, unless if you mean it *informally*.

Comment: I don't know anyone who says 'super chill'.

Comment: Using ***super*** as a general-purpose intensifier following the basic syntax of ***very, really, extremely,...*** is already quite "slangy". Using ***chill*** as an adjective with the vague sense of ***cool, hip, fashionable, trendy*** is also quite slangy. So using both together is imho *extremely* slangy - and the same applies if ***super*** is used to modify other adjectives such as ***mature*** or ***popular***.

Comment: Teenagers are always inventing phrases that they understand and nobody else does (at least for a while). In 1963 when Beatlemania started, saying 'fab gear' to mean, well, 'super chill' rapidly spread from Liverpool to the rest of the UK, at least among the under-20s. Kids in Britain say someone is 'peng' if they are attractive, although I suspect that if I know that, it is probably very obsolete.

Comment: Why would you think [super](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/super) which means "very or to an excessive degree" couldn't be used that way?

Answer (score 4):

In the sense used in your example, "Super" is an adverb.

An [adverb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adverb) according to Merriam Webster:

> a word that ... is often used to show time, manner, place, or **degree** [of something]

[Super](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/super) is defined as (by MW):

> **adverb**
>
> VERY, EXTREMELY; e.g. a *super* fast car

Here, you can see that "super" is being used to describe the *degree* to which something is doing something.  The car isn't just fast — it's fast to a large degree... super fast!

In your first example, you say that someone is "Chill to a large degree"; that is to say, "Very chill" or "Super chill".  So, **to answer your question, yes**.

You can feasibly say someone is "Super mature" or "Super popular".  Please note, however, that using "super" is considered informal (you shouldn't say you're "super good" at something in a job interview, for example); it's more something you would say to your friends.